# CSS Div under Div

Tags: css, material-design, flexbox, materialize

I'm having a lot of trouble setting a div to appear under another div (like they do normally).

I'musing MaterializeCSS. My layout is as follows:

```
<div class="container valign-wrapper">
    <div class="customClass"></div>
    <div class="customClass"></div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.valign-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.customClass{
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* text and font css */
}
```

However , even adding `width:100%` or changing display class won't make the two divs appear vertically, they appear side by side. I found out that removing `valign-wrapper` class will work, but my items will obviously appear at the top of the site...

If anyone has encountered the same problem I would appreciate the help!

Comment: `display: flex` adds some magic, but is you who need to manage this kind of magic with the child properties. If you don't know how flexbox works, please, use another technique (inline-block, float, table-cell, etc)

Comment: you forgt a `dot`, `.valign-wrapper` btw

Comment: My bad, but the dots were just missing here, not in the actual code...
@MarcosPérezGude i'm using a css framework, there's not much I can do

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the flex direction:

```
.valign-wrapper { flex-direction: column; }
```

That way, flex items are positioned as a column. Alternatively, if you need to go with `flex-direction: row;` (default), you can use

```
.valign-wrapper { flex-wrap: wrap; }
.customClass { flex-basis: 100%; }
```

to still maintain the row style but have your two items wrap and eventually positioned above each other.

Even though the post is from 2013, it still teaches the magic of flexbox in a nice way and I can just recommend everyone to read about it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This, or maybe just remove the valign-wrapper class from your container.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `flex-wrap: wrap` and `flex-basis: 100%` did the trick!